# Jquery problems with getting my Form to display successully sent or error messages correctly

Tags: ajax, jquery, forms

I have this code in a .js file that adjusts my form display when submitted by closing the form then displaying 'Message Successfully Sent' text or showing error messages like 'Error: message needs to be more than 200 characters or please insert a valid email address' etc.

The Form closing when the message is successfully sent works well and leaves just the message 'Message Successfully Sent', but the Form closing when there is an error does not work well because there is no way to return to the message to correct it.

Can anybody help me adapt the code so that the form only slidesup if the message is successfully sent, otherwise if there is an error the form stays visible but has the error message below, this way you can see the error and make the change in the form above, then press the send button again for a second attempt.

Here is code that I think needs changing, I am assuming it might be another state different than success: for the error stage?:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
   $("#send").attr("value", "Sending...");
   $(form).ajaxSubmit({
      success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
         $(form).slideUp("fast");
          $("#response").html(responseText + "<br/>").hide().slideDown("fast");
      }
   });
   return false;
}
```

`#send` is the send button and `#response` is the div that displays the response text.

I hope somebody can help. thanks.

Comment: Return a JSON object, with `error:` and `message:` properties. If error is true, leave the form open.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, that sounds good, any advice on how I do this and where I should place it in the code? Thanks for your help, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP script, return the result in JSON:

```
$result = array('error' => $error, 'message' => $response);
echo json_encode($result);
```

In jQuery, do:

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        if (!response.error) {
            $(form).slideUp("fast");
        }
        $("#response").html(response.message + "<br/>").hide().slideDown("fast");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I tried this but now my 'send' button doesn't respond at all? maybe I have put your code in the wrong place as I am sure what you have sent will be right. Here is a jsfiddle with the .js file content in full http://jsfiddle.net/vSVW4/. How can I show you the php code, can I upload this to the html area in Jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: My PHP code should replace whatever you currently do to print results in your server script. Instead of printing it, the output should be put into `$response`.  I'm not going to rewrite your entire application, I assume you're a competent programmer and can figure out how to integrate this into your application.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, no I wouldn't expect you to rewrite my entire application, just the help you are providing is really appreciated. Thanks. I will have a look and see if I can identify where your code show go, the php script is quite long as it has various error validation for email and the other forms, each output different error messages to a variable called $errors. I'll investigate some more. thanks

Comment: That should make it relatively easy. Check whether `$errors` contains anything, and set `$result['error']` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I have found this code which looks like it loops the errors and then displays them one after the other on the page. Is this where your code should go? 

if($errors) {
 // Output errors and die with a failure message
 $errortext = "";
 foreach($errors as $error) {
  $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
 }
 die("<span class='failure'>The following errors occured:<ul>". $errortext ."</ul></span>");
}